# Цифры в <input > сверяются с массивом регулярных выражений

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть массив с регулярными выражениями:

```
define(CODES, 
[
'[1][1-5][0-8]',
'[2][1-4][1-4]',
'[2][5][1-3]',
'[3][1-2][1-5]',
'[4][1-4][1-6]',
'[5][0-2][0]',
'[6][1-2][0]'
]);
```

Еще есть `<input>`, куда вводят 3 цифры. Как сделать так, если набор цифр в `<input>` не совпадает ни со одним регулярным выражением в массиве, сделать `$errors[] = 'Ошибка в коде!'` Как вы, наверное, заметили, одними `preg_match` и `foreach` здесь не отделаться. К примеру, если ввести '445' (валидно), то код ниже отработает как в `if`, так и `else`, что вполне логично. Как правильно сделать? Спасибо!

Кусок нерабочего кода:

```
    foreach(CODES as $item){
        if( !preg_match("~^{$item}$~", $_POST['code']) ){
            $errors[] = 'Ошибка в коде!';
        }
        else{
        ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вашу задачу можно решить компактней, и без использования цикла:

```
$_POST['code'] = 445; // Строка для теста
$errors = [];

define('CODES', [
    '[1][1-5][0-8]',
    '[2][1-4][1-4]',
    '[2][5][1-3]',
    '[3][1-2][1-5]',
    '[4][1-4][1-6]',
    '[5][0-2][0]',
    '[6][1-2][0]'
]);

preg_match('~^'. join('|', CODES) .'$~', $_POST['code']) ?: $errors[] = 'Ошибка в коде!';

print_r($errors);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Раньше не слышал о join() - только об implode().

Answer (score 1):

Создать переменную (например `$proceed`) и изменить ее, если данные  совпадает хотя бы с одним элементом массива.

```
$proceed = false;
foreach(CODES as $item){
    if ($proceed) continue;
    if (preg_match("~^{$item}$~", $_POST['code']) ){
        $proceed = true;
    }
}
if (!$proceed) {
    $errors[] = 'Ошибка в коде!';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Просто, как все гениальное!